# Query multiple tables and send query to Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to query multiple table and save the query as a global dictionary for further processing. I've tried the following, but instead of values I get the class name in the dictionary. Please take a look and show me what's wrong and where to read up more on `todictionary` queries?

```
  public class linqtosql
{
    public Dictionary<int, MC_VARIABLES> dctMC = new Dictionary<int, MC_VARIABLES>();

    public class MC_VARIABLES
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int UDLY_LAST { get; set; }
        public int STRIKE { get; set; }
        public decimal SKEW_A { get; set; }
        public decimal SKEW_B { get; set; }
        public double SKEW_C { get; set; }
    }

    public void GET_DATA()
    {

        var qryBOOK = from B in Globals.DATA.BOOKs
                      from O in Globals.DATA.OPTIONs
                      from U in Globals.DATA.UDLies
                      from S in Globals.DATA.SKEWs
                      where B.CONTRACT == O.CONTRACT
                      where O.UDLY_SYMBOL == U.UDLY_SYMBOL
                      where O.CONTRACT == S.CONTRACT
                      select new MC_VARIABLES
                      { ID = B.ID, STRIKE = (int)B.STRIKE, SKEW_A = (decimal)S.SKEW_A };

        dctMC = qryBOOK.ToDictionary(x => x.ID, x => x);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, MC_VARIABLES> KVP in dctMC)
        {
            var key = KVP.Key;
            var item = KVP.Value.SKEW_A;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `qryBOOK.ToDictionary(x => x.ID, x => x)`

Comment: @Hari, thanks that compiles, but I get funny values for the dictionary values ``[0] = {[3, nmMONTECARLO.linqtosql+MC_VARIABLES]}``. There is something else wrong,

Comment: `MC_VARIABLES firstItem = qryBOOK[0];` do this and see we have `MC_VARIABLES` instance and properties are readable.

Comment: @Zeus That's correct. It's saying `The first entry has the key '3', with the value of 'nmMONTECARLO.linqtosql+MC_VARIABLES]'` (since you haven't overriden the ToString(). You should see a + next to the class name which will expand it and show the values.

Comment: tks, this is new to me. How do I get the values?, should I add ToString?  I would like to reference the values later in the program. If I add  ``MC_VARIABLES firstItem = qryBOOK[0];`` I get an error ``"Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'IQueriable<...>"``

Comment: I thought I'd get the values using ``dctMC(key).SKEW_A``  etc and loop through the keys

Comment: @Zeus You don't need to do anything further to get the values. It doesn't work for you because you need to write something like this: `MC_Variables myThing = dctMC[3]; var last = myThing.UDLY_LAST; .. etc` (if `3` was a valid ID of one of the elements you loaded)

Comment: @Rob, ok, but I won't know before running the code what the IDs will be, they could be 1 to 20 so I'd like to loop over the keys of the dictionary. Is this possible using a foreach... like in the question? (see edit)

Comment: ok tks, see what you mean on how to get values out, just need to figure out how to loop through keys since they'll form dynamically

Comment: for other users...dctMC is a keyvaluepair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `x => x` instead of `x => MC_VARIABLES`, x is of type MC_VARIABLES in this case.

```
qryBOOK.ToDictionary(x => x.ID, x => x)
```